# Removing Pocket PC pollution from VC++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, project

I have a VC++ project in VS 2005 that I make 32 and 64bit releases of.  I just installed VS 2010 and am trying to port the project to the newer Visual Studio.  It won't port because the project references the platform "Pocket PC 2003 (ARMV4)".

I have never created any project for Pocket PC.  I don't know why this is device exists as an Option under Device Tools.

VS 2010 does not support this device, and won't convert my 2005 project because of it.  How to I remove un-needed devices from my old project.

Thanks,
Gerry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the project/solution files in a text editor and manually remove the references to it.

Answer (score 1):

Build + Configuration Manager.  Upper right combo (Active solution platform), pick Edit.  Select the unwanted platform and click Remove.

Comment: Nope, I tried this and it did not work.  The solution above to manually edit the project and solution files did the trick.

Comment: @Gerry - please mark posts that were helpful, it is what keeps SO going.  Sure sounds to me that @Blindy's post was helpful to you, it deserves the upvote.